# Why doesn't this Kendo Grid editor template work with an Autocomplete widget?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-autocomplete

I have the following Kendo Grid:

```
$("#teachers").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
        { field: "employeeId", title: "Employee Id" },
        { field: "firstName", title: "First Name", editor: categoryDropDownEditor },
        { field: "lastName", title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "isHeadmaster", title: "Is a Headmaster?" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "153px" }],
    editable: 'popup'
});
```

The problem I have isn't with the grid, it's with the editor template -- as you can see I'm using popup editing and I'd like to give one of the fields an autocomplete selection widget.

Here's how `categoryDropDownEditor` is defined:

```
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: [
                "Albania",
                "Andorra",
                "Armenia",
                /* ... */
                "Ukraine",
                "United Kingdom",
                "Vatican City"
            ],
            filter: "startswith"
        });
}
```

(I cannibalized this function from the samples [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-custom.html) and [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/autocomplete/index.html).)

The autocomplete widget doesn't work at all, no matter what I type. No suggestions show up, at all. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are setting the data-text-field and data-value-field, but binding to a list of strings.  Simply remove the data-text-field and data-value-field.  Or you can leave them, but the dataSource will need to be a list of objects with the properties you specify in the data-text-field and data-value-field.

See working sample...  http://jsbin.com/mawik/1/edit